# Repeating background in CSS - framerate drops when scrolling downwards

Tags: html, css

I've just set up a repeating background (url) on my site's blog which is 480 x 300 in size.

However, i've noticed a framerate loss when i scroll downwards -- the page just doesn't scroll downwards smoothly anymore compared to the old background-color based layout. I'm thinking its because of the rendering needed to repeat the background.

Is there anyway to optimize my background to load fast while improving framerate as well? Would a 1920x1200 background be better than the one that i'm using now? (480 x 300)?

Oh and i'm referring to the blog section: http://blog.aptitudedigital.com/

(Site is still WIP, but i'd appreciate suggestions in comments below)

Comment: what is your background image? All I can see from your link is a black solid background.

Comment: Ah, the days when hardware-accelerated browsers were mere farcical pipe dreams...

Comment: its actually a subtle patterned background, but i'm still fiddling with the site as of now so...yeah. (i didn't expect a reply so soon)

Comment: It's a speckled dark gray background. Typically, you won't want a background image that big, because browsers have to read that image every time they see it. Try making it 40x40 or so. Also, the background of the page isn't the only thing making it lag, I also noticed it when I'd scroll past a block of information.

Comment: but wouldn't 40x40 tax the system even more? or am i misunderstanding something here? (i mean, just a question)

Comment: Sorry, I said that wrong. Older browsers read a smaller background image poorly, but current browsers are fine. IE7+ will be fine with a repeating background image. But 1900x1200 is way too big for any background on the web.

Comment: Hmm, changed the background to 40x40, seems a lot better now.

Comment: @Torr3nt , could you explain in an answer below? I'd accept it, and while you're at that maybe you could also explain in a simple manner why a smaller px repeating background would help in framerates and rendering. That would help a lot of newbies trying out repeating backgrounds and not having a clue.